# Skip over errors when looping throgh yahoo finance tickers with yfinance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am downloading data from yahoo finance with yfinance in Python and looping through a few hundred tickers but randomly I get an error with some of the tickers which breaks the whole process.

Is there a way to kind of capture the exception and continue with the loop but just ignore that 'faulty' ticker when there is an error so I don't have to start from the beginning every time?

This is my code

```
stockslist = pd.read_csv('KuCoins.csv')

combined = yf.download("SPY", start ="2022-01-01", end="2022-01-02")
 
for index, row in stockslist.iterrows():
   ticker = (row['ticker'])
  
   
   data = yf.download(ticker, start ="2022-03-01", end=currentDate)
```

and this is the error I get:

**
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:

- KDON-USD: No data found, symbol may be delisted
  Traceback (most recent call last):

Exception: inputs are all NaN
**

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `stockslist` so we can reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try-except block to handle with that.

```
for index, row in stockslist.iterrows():
    try:
        ticker = (row['ticker'])
        data = yf.download(ticker, start ="2022-03-01", end=currentDate)
    except Exception as e:
         print ("There is an issue with ticker: {} and we are passing it".format(ticker))
         pass
```